# Browser says "Camera Blocked to protect your privacy"

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webcam, camera

Browser says "**Camera Blocked to protect your privacy**"

My project include using user camera and when i access application from localhost camera works fine but when accessing through ipaddress, the browser by default blocks the camera and other resource.. how can i allow them for my application.

[image]

My application is for an organization who will be accessing the application using ipaddress.
Thank you for reading and your help. :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. type url chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
2. Enter url in the textarea
3. Choose Enabled in the select option
   Click image link bellow to see detail

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt44L.png)

Answer (score 14):

Chrome blocks vulnerable features—including camera, location, microphone, etc. on non-secure sites. As of July 2018, with the release of Chrome 68, [Chrome starts to mark all HTTP sites as "not secure."](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure)

You have three options to unblock these features for your site:

1. Treat `192.168.10.79` as secure origins by setting `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`. Origins must have their protocol specified, e.g., `http://192.168.10.79`.
2. Port forwarding your site address to `localhost`. Chrome treats `localhost` as secure origins.
3. Set up a self-signed certificate for the server.

Answer (score 7):

### The problem is because of http protocol. This is not a secure protocol.

---

### Solution

**In my scenario I have used https and have got all permissions.**